# CSS - Concentric circles

Tags: css, geometry

I want to create two concentric circles in CSS. The inner one has a specified width compaired to the outer one, e.g. 50%. Those circles should be responsive, they should scale properly for all screens.

How can I do this? I prefer not to use position:absolute, javascript or jQuery. I think it should be possible.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you specify how they should "scale properly"? What would they scale in relation to?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on what the circles should be, or is there complete freedom in that respect? (image, rectangles with really big border radius, div with a background image, etc)

Comment: It's easy if the inner circle has position absolute. Why wouldn't you use it ? (I can undertand not wanting to use scripting, but I see no arguments about position ...)

Comment: part of the answer is on your image: `border-radius: 50%`

Comment: @Guffa: on a screen two times the screen size of the other, the circle should be two times as big

Comment: @Vals because the element should follow the content flow

Answer (score 12):

Pure CSS:

```
#container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#circle {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   background-color: #000000;
   border-radius: 50%;
}

#small-circle{
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="circle">
      <div id="small-circle">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RV5b4/)

Comment: your solution is good but we can acheive this with ::before or ::after as well, If you are comfortable I can edit the code for your solution

Comment: @zakir you can achieve it in multiple ways. I don't like pseudo elements, if you want to add them a nested element for example, it's not possible. You can add your own answer with this solution if you feel it has an added value :)

Answer (score 4):

Ah ... svg can help?
You can use CSS on it's elements if needed, but I think you can do it strict and simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <svg>
            <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="40" fill='red' stroke-width="20" stroke='black'/ >
        </svg>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: nice one. Seems like a better alternative to CSS graphics. And browser support looks pretty good

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mG3KJ/1/

```
#outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
}
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: IT is responsive, but it is sometimes an ellipse. Make it always a circle this way  http://jsfiddle.net/mG3KJ/2/

Comment: Very nice, but is there an easy way to set the percentage of the inner CSS? Now it's always 50. I will be needing f.e. one with 70%, 75%, ..

Comment: @user3103099 What do you mean? You can simply change the percentage?

Comment: I'm making graphs. The circles represent an amount.
The outer circle is 100%, the inner circle is in this case 50%; but sometimes the circle will have to be bigger, e.g. if I want to visualise 70/100; I'll need a bigger circle. Changing the width and height of the inner div to 70% would work, but then the inner circle is not in the center of the outer circle anymore.

Comment: @user3103099 it really isn't that hard, the `left` and `top` properties have to have the half of (100% - the width). So when you want the inner circle to be 70%, then you set your left and top to `((100-70) /2)% = 15%`.